# SourceImage as Google storage bucket link while inserting new image

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

What should be the proper format to provide Google storage image link while `images.insert` ?
Image file located at GS Bucket as `*.tar.gz`.
Creating new image with google client library in python with api `images.insert(body=body,project=project)`

my body config looks like:

```
body = { "name":"test", "sourceImage":"https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/[BUCKET]/[IMAGEFILE]",}
```

Procedure fails with following error:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting  returned "Invalid value for field 'resource.sourceImage': 'https://storag
e.cloud.google.com/[BUCKET]/[IMAGEFILE]'. The URL is malformed.">
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9741888/temu, Hi Temu thanks for answering earlier questoin. Do you know where i went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access an image from Google storage, please use [“rawDisk”](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/insert) instead. Here is an example:

```
"name": "image-1",
  "rawDisk": {
    "source": "https://storage.googleapis.com/[bucket]/[imagefile]"
  }
```

Where [bucket] is the name of your bucket and [imagefile] = *.tar.gz